# Keep every user last 100 transaction and delete the rest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name tbl_tmp_trans
it contains every user transactions ever done ( and it's up to 6Mil right now !)

we have decided to keep only last 100 transaction per user in our database so we could keep the db clean
here is a query that i have came up with

```
delete  from tbl_tmp_trans 
where   trans_id in 
(
    select  trans_id 
    from 
    (
        select  trans_id 
        from    tbl_faucets_transactions 
        order   by date 
        group   by user_id 
        limit   100
    ) foo 
)
```

what am i doing wrong?

because after doing this my cpu reach 100% and mysql crashed.

Thanks in advance
P.S: our db is Mysql and table engine is Innodb

P.S2: We have about 120k and transction table have near 6 million record

Comment: not sure how many users you have in your system, but you might want to take this query and add another parameter (userid) to it, so you're not trying to run through the entire database all in one shot.

Comment: @user2366842 We have about 120k user

Comment: Please show EXPLAIN result.

Comment: @MarcusAdams every time i run this query mysql crashes .. i cant

Comment: I prefere to delete older transactions when a user execute a transaction

Comment: Then give us more info. Indexes, row counts, etc. E.g. if you remove the `LIMIT 100` on the inner query, how many rows?

Comment: And such a subselect with so many entries is not a good idea and your problem... ;)

Comment: @A.Blub so could you suggest me a query to do that at least? i cant think of any

Comment: @MarcusAdams: indexes: date (unixtimestam) , user id , trans_id(primary) , not sure by what you mean at remove the LIMIT 100 on the inner

Comment: I need much more informations to make you a seroius solution. I dont know much of your structure and so on. Lets try only a small change: Add at your subselect `WHERE user_id = '<any user_id>'` and look for a result and how long it takes

Comment: this subselect is not even syntactically correct (you have order by before group by), or is it? or something is missing from the sample?

Comment: @lp_ i know i have wrote the query on the fly here

Comment: ok I see... but even if the group-order would be after each other, it would just return some trans_ids for some 100 users, so no surprises that it is not working, however, it is interesting that mysql crashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a proposal... Hopefully, it might help you.

Alter your table:

```
alter table tbl_tmp_trans add column todel tinyint(1);
```

Implement a stored procedure to iterate through the table with a cursor and mark (set `todel` to `1`) records that should be deleted. Example procedure to do that:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists mark_old_transactions //
create procedure mark_old_transactions()
begin
    declare done int default false;
    declare tid int;
    declare uid int;
    declare last_uid int default 0;
    declare count int default 0;
    declare cur cursor for select trans_id, user_id from tbl_tmp_trans order by user_id, date desc;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

    open cur;
    repeat
        fetch cur into tid, uid;
        if (!done) then
            if (uid!=last_uid) then
                set count = 0;
            end if;
            set last_uid = uid;
            set count = count + 1;
            if (count > 100) then
                update tbl_tmp_trans set todel=1 where trans_id=tid;
            end if;
        end if;
    until done
    end repeat;
    close cur;
end //
```

Invoke the procedure, maybe do some simple checks (how many transactions you delete from the table, etc.), and delete the marked records.

```
call mark_old_transactions;
-- select count(*) from tbl_tmp_trans where todel=1;
-- select count(*) from tbl_tmp_trans;
delete from tbl_tmp_trans where todel=1;
```

Finally, remove the column that we just added.

```
alter table tbl_tmp_trans drop column todel;
```

Some notes:

- Probably you have to iterate through all the records of the table
  anyway, so you don't loose performance with the cursor.
- If you have ~120K users and ~6M transactions, you have ~50 transactions per user on average. Which means, that probably you don't really
  have too many users with transactions over 100, so the number of
  updates (hopefully) won't be too many. => the procedure runs relatively fast.
- Delete should be fast again with the new column.